# Group isomorphic to its automorphism group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Any complete group (that is, with trivial center and outer automorphism group) is isomorphic to its automorphism group. The inverse is not true, as the dihedral group of order 8 is isomorphic to its automorphism group but isn't complete.

Problem 15.29 in the Kourovka Notebook asks to find another exemple of a p-group, but I was wondering, is any other exemple known? Is there any other finite (or even infinite) group (not necessarily a p-group) which is isomorphic to its automorphism group but isn't complete?

Comment: The dihedral group of order $12$ is another (non $p$-group) example. By [this link](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2022/09/14/automorphisms-of-dihedral-groups) the automorphism group of $D_{2n}$ has order $n\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function, so there are no other finite dihedral examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The infinite dihedral group $G=D_{\infty}$ is also isomorphic to its own automorphism group, but is not complete - see the article [A Note on Groups with Just-Infinite Automorphism Groups](http://siba-ese.unisalento.it/index.php/notemat/article/viewFile/12869/11463).

For finite groups, not $p$-groups, not complete, it is said [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_isomorphic_to_its_automorphism_group): "Whether there exist other groups isomorphic to their automorphism groups is an open problem". For more results, see the article [On a question about automorphisms of finite p-groups](http://www.dma.unina.it/cutolo/papers/JGT06.pdf) by G. Cutolo. See also [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258886/conditions-for-a-finite-group-to-be-isomorphic-to-its-automorphism-group).