# classification of self automorphic groups

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

I will refer to a group as self automorphic if it is isomorphic to its automorphism group, that is, its group of automorphisms. For example, the group $S_3$ is self automorphic.

I have two questions:
(1) Is there a classification of the finite self automorphic groups? If so please let me know where I can read about this classification.
(2) Is there a classification of the countable self automorphic groups?

Seeing as that there apears to not be a complete classification of these groups, could you give an example other than a symmetric group or the group $D_8$? Thanks

Comment: I don't believe a full list is known.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433055/group-isomorphic-to-its-automorphism-group) for more information.

Comment: are you saying you beleive a full list is not known for the finite case or the countable case? Thanks

Comment: A believe that no full list is known in either case.  To be clear:  I could be wrong about that.

Comment: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258886/conditions-for-a-finite-group-to-be-isomorphic-to-its-automorphism-group) is more information on the finite case.

Comment: No, a classification sounds hopeless even in the realm of finite groups. Still, many subcases are known, e.g., among finite Coxeter groups, or among finite simple groups.